# friend and inheritance functionality

Tags: c++, inheritance

I want to ask what is preferable in usage in programming friend relation between classes

or inheritance its seems to me both functionality are 1 except that friend can access private members while inheritance just to access protected members

Comment: _"friend and inheritance functionality"_ ... are orthogonal features.

Comment: What is better? F22 air superiority aircraft or B2 stealth bomber?

Comment: Which is better ? Mac or PC ? Well it boils down to personal preference and situation.Same with friend and inheritance

Comment: @user3670482: The B-52, of course. Still the king of all aircraft.

Comment: How old are you Jerry? :)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ ,orthogonal o.O didn't get it

Comment: @Akshay L Aradhya got it :)

Comment: @OmarKhaled -> unrelated

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance and friendship are completely different kinds of relationships.

If class B inherits from class A, that means B actually is an A. One single object of type B is also of type A. The details about accessing public and protected members just define how one B object is able to access the A part of itself.

If class B declares friendship to class A, then that's entirely different. A is not a B. B is not an A. The relationship only says that an object of type A can access the private parts of an object of type B. But they're still separate objects.

Answer (score 1):

Friendship and inheritance are *different* concepts in C++. You use friendship to grant otherwise unrelated class the access to the other class's data while inheritance to express such a design relationships like *isa* ( public) or *is-implemented-in-terms-of* ( protected, private).